# Unable to Cast Object of type 'System.Boolean' to type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, sql

Hi I get this error when I try running the program.  I believe its because in SQL Server this a True or False? 1 or 0? Would anyone know how to fix?

```
  void StaticS()
    {

        string constring = "REMOVED";
        string Query = "REMOVED";
        SqlConnection conDataBase = new SqlConnection(constring);
        SqlCommand cmdDataBase = new SqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
        SqlDataReader myReader;
        try
        {
            conDataBase.Open();
            myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();

            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                string sName = myReader.GetString(0);
                comboBox17.Items.Add(sName);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string sName = myReader[0].ToString();
```

If you want to get only string representation of value from DataReader without paying attention on real value type - you may use DataReader indexer and just call ToString() method.

Comment: Wow such an easy Fix haha. Thanks!

Comment: Please can you explain this?

Comment: Sorry but explain what? Why I've proposed to use indexer and ToString() instead of GetBoolean()? Because of requested in question return value of this operation.

Comment: @DmytroRudenko Explain the snippet. Even if it's small and seems obvious, answers should be more than just a code dump. It's the same as the expectation that questions actually explain the problem. For example: Why doesn't the OP's attempt work and what's different about this that lets it?

Comment: @DmytroRudenko It's not too late to edit the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Look at this line:

```
string sName = myReader.GetString(0);
```

The `GetString` method returns `string`, so there is no casting in the code here. But `GetString` itself is implemented by reading field `0` and attempting to cast it to a `string`. It would seem that field `0` is a boolean field, and there is no automatic conversion from boolean to string. Hence `GetString()` fails.

Instead you can perform the conversion explicitly:

```
string sName = myReader[0].ToString();
```

Here, `myReader[0]` reads the field and returns the value as `object`. And then it's up to you how to turn that into a string.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like field 0 is a `bit` field, in which case you'd use:

```
bool sName = myReader.GetBoolean(0);
```